# Trim trailing spaces before each new line in a multi-line string

Tags: filter, replace

I have a string from a multi-line plain text field and I'd like to trim any trailing spaces before new lines.

With plain regex I would use this expression: `/\s*$/gm`

Using

```
{{ string|replace('/\\s*$/', '') }}
```

will trim out the last trailing space of the string (same as the `trim` filter would), but not before every new line.

I have tried

```
{{ string|replace('/\\s*$/gm', '') }}
```

and

```
{{ string|replace('/\\s*$/m', '') }}
```

but that doesn't have any effect.

How can I apply the `m modifier` to the replace filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently it’s not possible to pass regex modifiers to the `|replace` filter. You’d have to just do this manually:

```
{% set str = "foo     \nbar    " %}
{% set trimmed = "" %}

{% for line in str|split("\n") %}
    {% set trimmed = trimmed ~ (trimmed ? "\n") ~ line|replace('/\\s*$/', '') %}
{% endfor %}
```

**UPDATE**

As of Craft 2.5, the `|replace` filter supports regex modifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Just needed something similar today, and patched in a new replace filter to the [RetconHTML plugin](https://github.com/mmikkel/RetconHTML-Craft). The filter – called `retconReplace` – uses `preg_replace` and might be able to help you out:

```
{{ string|retconReplace('/\s*$/m') }}
```

You'll find the wiki on `retconReplace` [here](https://github.com/mmikkel/RetconHTML-Craft/wiki/Replace).

Comment: That’s awesome, thanks Mats. And your plugin has come in very handy on another site I've been working on :)

Answer (score 0):

Would the `spaceless` [filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/spaceless.html) work wrapped in div?

Comment: If you run the field value through `|spaceless` (with or without a div), it will only remove the whitespace at the outer edges of the text; not all of the trailing whitespace on each line of the text.