# Best way to do a multi-line regex replace?

Tags: regex, replace

I understand that for a long time the `|replace` filter has [supported regex modifiers](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/11618/3507), but I can't seem to get the syntax right for multiline searches.

For example, here I want to extract the internal markup within a list that's been generated via Markdown, so I can do something with the internals:

```
{% set html = html|replace('/\\n/', '')|replace('/^(<ul>)(.*)(<\\/ul>)$/', '$2') %}
```

That works, but I should be able to use a modifier with the second replace so I don't have to use the first one, right?

But none of these work:

```
{% set html = html|replace('/^(<ul>)(.*)(<\\/ul>)$/m', '$2') %}

{% set html = html|replace('/^(<ul>)(.*)(<\\/ul>)$/\\m', '$2') %}

{% set html = html|replace('/^(<ul>)(.*)(<\\/ul>)$/(?m)', '$2') %}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm on my phone, so I'm not able to test, but it looks to me like your regex is explicitly expecting the string you're testing to start with `<ul>` and end with `</ul>`, and despite the multiline flag, any line breaks at the start or end of the string will prevent a match.

Try removing the `^` and `$` from the start and end your pattern match to disable explicit start and end of string matching.